# Problem with Reading Rx buffer in SPI STM32

Tags: c, stm32, spi, coocox

I have little bit problem when reading Rx Buffer in STM32 SPI. I can watch my signal when transmit or receive in my scope. But I never can get any data in my Rx Buffer. I just use coocox software for this project.

For this project, I use STM32F103 and LoRa module (SX1278). I use Full duplex communication for my SPI Configuration. There is 2 cycle to read register status in my LoRa module. First cycle is to write address and second cycle is for read/write register. My problem is reading register in my LoRa module.

This is my simple code to read register.

```
  void SPI2_IRQHandler(void)
  {
       RxSPIBuff = &Buffer_Rx[0];
       if (SPI_I2S_GetITStatus(SPI2, SPI_I2S_IT_RXNE) == SET)
       {
          /* Store the I2S2 received data in the relative data table */
          //Buffer_Rx[RxIdx++] = SPI_I2S_ReceiveData(SPI2);
         //if (SPI_I2S_GetITStatus(SPI2, SPI_I2S_FLAG_RXNE)==SET)
            USART_SendData(USART1, SPI_I2S_ReceiveData(SPI2));
       }
  }

 void InitSPI_Lora(void)
 {
SPI_InitTypeDef SPI_InitStruct;
GPIO_InitTypeDef GPIO_InitStructure;
NVIC_InitTypeDef NVIC_InitStructure;

// RCC Peripheral Configuration
RCC_APB2PeriphClockCmd(RCC_APB2Periph_AFIO, ENABLE);
RCC_APB1PeriphClockCmd(RCC_APB1Periph_SPI2, ENABLE);
RCC_APB2PeriphClockCmd(RCC_APB2Periph_GPIOB, ENABLE);

// GPIO Configuration
GPIO_InitStructure.GPIO_Pin = MOSI_LoRa | SCLK_LoRa;
GPIO_InitStructure.GPIO_Mode = GPIO_Mode_AF_PP;
GPIO_InitStructure.GPIO_Speed = GPIO_Speed_50MHz;
GPIO_Init(SPI_LoRa, &GPIO_InitStructure);

GPIO_InitStructure.GPIO_Pin = NSS_LoRa;
GPIO_InitStructure.GPIO_Mode = GPIO_Mode_Out_PP;
GPIO_InitStructure.GPIO_Speed = GPIO_Speed_50MHz;
GPIO_Init(PeriphNSS_LoRa, &GPIO_InitStructure);

GPIO_InitStructure.GPIO_Pin = MISO_LoRa;
GPIO_InitStructure.GPIO_Mode = GPIO_Mode_IPU;
GPIO_InitStructure.GPIO_Speed = GPIO_Speed_50MHz;
GPIO_Init(SPI_LoRa, &GPIO_InitStructure);

GPIO_InitStructure.GPIO_Pin = Reset_LoRa;
GPIO_InitStructure.GPIO_Mode = GPIO_Mode_Out_PP;
GPIO_InitStructure.GPIO_Speed = GPIO_Speed_50MHz;
GPIO_Init(PeriphRst_LoRa, &GPIO_InitStructure);

GPIO_InitStructure.GPIO_Pin = DIO0_LoRa;
GPIO_InitStructure.GPIO_Mode = GPIO_Mode_Out_PP;
GPIO_InitStructure.GPIO_Speed = GPIO_Speed_50MHz;
GPIO_Init(PeriphDI0_LoRa, &GPIO_InitStructure);

// SPI Configuration
SPI_InitStruct.SPI_BaudRatePrescaler=SPI_BaudRatePrescaler_32; // 7us every 8 bit data
SPI_InitStruct.SPI_CPHA=SPI_CPHA_1Edge;
SPI_InitStruct.SPI_CPOL=SPI_CPOL_Low;
SPI_InitStruct.SPI_DataSize=SPI_DataSize_8b;
SPI_InitStruct.SPI_Direction=SPI_Direction_2Lines_FullDuplex;
SPI_InitStruct.SPI_FirstBit=SPI_FirstBit_MSB;
SPI_InitStruct.SPI_Mode=SPI_Mode_Master;
SPI_InitStruct.SPI_NSS=SPI_NSS_Soft;

// NVIC Configuration
NVIC_PriorityGroupConfig(NVIC_PriorityGroup_0);
/* SPI1 IRQ Channel configuration */
NVIC_InitStructure.NVIC_IRQChannel = SPI2_IRQn;
NVIC_InitStructure.NVIC_IRQChannelPreemptionPriority = 1;
NVIC_InitStructure.NVIC_IRQChannelSubPriority = 0;
NVIC_InitStructure.NVIC_IRQChannelCmd = ENABLE;
NVIC_Init(&NVIC_InitStructure);

SPI_I2S_DeInit(SPI2);

/* Enable the I2S1 RxNE interrupt */
SPI_I2S_ITConfig(SPI2, SPI_I2S_IT_RXNE, ENABLE);

SPI_Init(SPI2, &SPI_InitStruct);
SPI_Cmd(SPI2, ENABLE);
 }

 void SendSPI_Lora(unsigned short val, unsigned char status)
 {
SPI_I2S_SendData(SPI2, val);
while(SPI_I2S_GetITStatus(SPI2, SPI_I2S_FLAG_TXE)==SET);
SPI_I2S_ClearFlag(SPI2, SPI_I2S_FLAG_TXE);
 }


 void AccessSPI(unsigned char Cmd, unsigned short *ptrBuff, unsigned char    Operation)
 {
unsigned short m, temp;

NSS_LO_LoRa;
SendSPI_Lora(Cmd, kWriteSPI);       // Send Command
if (Operation==kWriteSPI)
{
    temp=*ptrBuff;
    SendSPI_Lora(temp, Operation);
}
else
{
    RxIdx=0;
    SendSPI_Lora(0, Operation);
    ptrBuff = RxSPIBuff;
}
Delay(2);
NSS_HI_LoRa;
 }

 // Main Sequence
 void test(void)
 {
unsigned char statusLoRa,buff,irqFlags,newData,newOpMode;
unsigned char size = 0;

AccessSPI(R_REGISTER|RegVersion, &newOpMode, kReadSPI);
 }
```

[image]
Pict 1. Write signal in MOSI pin

[image]
Pict 2. Read Signal in MISO pin

I think my problem is about delay to receive data after transmit data with SPI. But i cannot solve this problem because i should transmit data to receive. Is there any solution for this?

Answer (score 1):

1. I'm not sure about this one, but I think MISO should also be configured as alternate mode. At least that's what works for me.
2. You have configured RXNE interrupt, but use TXE as interrupt also.
   Use `SPI_I2S_GetFlagStatus` instead of `SPI_I2S_GetITStatus`
3. `while(SPI_I2S_GetITStatus(SPI2, SPI_I2S_FLAG_TXE)==SET);` is an error. [Reference manual for STM32F103](https://www.st.com/content/ccc/resource/technical/document/reference_manual/59/b9/ba/7f/11/af/43/d5/CD00171190.pdf/files/CD00171190.pdf/jcr:content/translations/en.CD00171190.pdf), page 710:

   > The TXE flag (Tx buffer empty) is set when the data are transferred from the Tx buffer to the shift register. It indicates that the internal Tx buffer is ready to be loaded with the next data.

   So it should be `while(SPI_I2S_GetFlagStatus(SPI2, SPI_I2S_FLAG_TXE)==RESET);`
4. With RXNE interrupt you will be sending to USART also after sending the first byte (the register addess)

   [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58271313/1981374) is a CMSIS code for similar transmission ("First cycle is to write address and second cycle is for read/write register.", but without using interrupts, and using STM32F4 with SPI configured as follows:

   ```
   //af5, afrl
   GPIOB->AFR[0] |= ( GPIO_AFRL_AFSEL3_2 | GPIO_AFRL_AFSEL3_0 |
                      GPIO_AFRL_AFSEL5_2 | GPIO_AFRL_AFSEL5_0 );
   GPIOA->AFR[0] |= ( GPIO_AFRL_AFSEL6_2 | GPIO_AFRL_AFSEL6_0 );
   //B3 SCK
   //A6 MISO
   //B5 MOSI
   //B6 SS
   GPIOA->MODER |= ( GPIO_MODER_MODE6_1 );
   GPIOB->MODER |= ( GPIO_MODER_MODE3_1 |
                     GPIO_MODER_MODE5_1 |
                     GPIO_MODER_MODE6_0 ); //alternate, 6 output

   GPIOA->PUPDR &= ~(GPIO_PUPDR_PUPD6_Msk ); // no pull
   GPIOB->PUPDR |= GPIO_PUPDR_PUPD3_1;
   ```
5. Are you using a Nano board? If so into which connector did you plug your MISO? I've spent a  week once because I have plugged it into Arduino connector that was connected to some other peripheral instead of Morpho connector.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I have converted SPI_I2S_GetITStatus with SPI_I2S_GetFlagStatus , but it doesn't give any significant result. I don't use nano board. I use STM32F103 board from LC Technology.

Comment: @calvinlimantara have you tried changing MISO to AF? Also I can't find `SPI_I2S_ReceiveData` in [Description of STM32F1 HAL and Low-layer drivers](https://www.st.com/content/ccc/resource/technical/document/user_manual/72/52/cc/53/05/e3/4c/98/DM00154093.pdf/files/DM00154093.pdf/jcr:content/translations/en.DM00154093.pdf)